# Calling Win32::API SendMessage for a ListBox that returns Struct

Tags: perl, winapi, sendmessage

I have a ListBox in a Windows app that lists the people in a chat session. This is defined as follows:

```
Win32::API::Struct->typedef('UserItem', qw {
                                                USHORT uid;
                                                TCHAR realName[256];
                                                TCHAR aliasName[256];
                                            }
                       ) or die "Typedef error $! \n";

my $user_data = Win32::API::Struct->new('UserItem');
```

Now I want to send a LB_GETITEMDATA message to the window to the get the attendee item details defined by the struct.

Using Win32::API, I do this:

```
my $LB_GETITEMDATA = 0x0199;
my $SendMessage = Win32::API->new("user32", "SendMessage", "NNNN", "S");
... # Here is the code to find the window handle, which is $hwnd.
$user_data = $SendMessage->Call($hwnd, $LB_GETITEMDATA, 0, 0); # Get the first item.
```

Now, I'd think $user_data struct will contain the first item's details, but it is actually undef & I don't get any LB_ERR either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes no senses to me. How can Win32::API know what kind of struct is being returned by SendMessage if you don't tell it? It can't possibly create the right type of object from the information you provided it.

I see nothing on how to use "S" for the return value. I think you might have to use the prototype interface if you want to return value to be unpacked into a ::Struct object. That's the only one documented.

But before you start messing with that, change the return type to "N" and see if you get a pointer back. If you get zero, it could be a problem with the listbox or with the arguments (particularly, the handle or the message number, since "NNNN" looks right to me), and you should fix that first. Then you can worry about the return value if it's still a problem.

If it is a problem with getting ::Struct to work, you could always unpack the 
structure yourself.

```
 # Use "N" for return.
 my ($uid, $realName, $aliasName) =
    unpack('S Z256 Z256',                # Unpack fields of structure.
       unpack('P514', pack('J', $rv)));  # Get bytes of the structure.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this cleared up a lot of confusion for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the item data with LB_SETITEMDATA after adding the string. The data is just a pointer sized value so each $user_data struct has to exist in memory as long as the item exists in the list...

Comment: I'm a little confused, mostly due to lack of knowledge on my part, so bear with me. The ListBox already lists the item, I just want to read it. So could you please elaborate on what you mean by "set the item data"?

Comment: A normal non-ownerdraw listbox stores one 0 terminated string per item but you can also store an additional pointer sized number as extra data for each item. Use LB_GETTEXT to get the string and LB_SETITEMDATA/LB_GETITEMDATA to manipulate the extra/bonus data.

Comment: OK, I searched for extra data part & I found a similar problem & solution here - http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/95254-listbox-extra-data-storage.html#post684026. So if I change the fourth parameter for Win32::API constructor to "N" (since the return is not a pointer), I get an integer back and it looks like it is the address of location of data, which is my struct. How do I create a pointer to that location of the type (my struct) 'UserItem',  in Perl? Any suggestions?

Comment: unpack ( http://linux.die.net/man/1/perlpacktut ) maybe? (BTW, SendMessage takes PIPP and returns P as far as the sizes of the types go, you must get this right if you want it to work as a 64bit app)

Comment: @Anders, NNNN is appropriate here. It allows him to pass NULL easily, and there's no way to make P work for the handle. As for the second argument, it is unsigned, so N is appropriate and I isn't.

Comment: @ikegami: I thought N would give you network byte order? Either way, N would not work as a native x64 app, you would need a type that is sizeof(void*)...

Comment: @Anders, Win32::API's `N` and `pack`'s `N` are different. And your claim that the DLL suddenly takes different arguments if it's called from a "native x64 app" makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami: WPARAM, LPARAM and LRESULT are 32bit on i386 and 64 bit on amd64 (assuming you are using a x64 version of perl on win64)

Comment: @Andrers, It's not possible to have two functions with the same name in the same C library -- C isn't polymorphic -- so what you say is not true or not relevant. To my knowlege, the `SendMessage` function of user32.dll takes 32-bit args. Prove me wrong.

Comment: @ikegami: On Win64 there are two copies of user32.dll, one for 32 bit apps and one for 64 bit apps